# app crashes while opening navigation drawer....there is no error shown....app just shuts down

Tags: android, android-studio, uinavigationbar

```
package com.example.pratik.womensafety;
```

import android.content.Intent;

import android.graphics.Typeface;

import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;

import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class AccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
TextView t;
TextView g;
private Button mLogout;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private DrawerLayout mLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mLayout =(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close);
    mLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);






    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));

    }

    FirebaseUser user =mAuth.getCurrentUser();

     t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intro);
    Typeface myCustomFont= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Ostrichfontd.otf");
    t.setTypeface(myCustomFont);

    g= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
    g.setTypeface(myCustomFont);

    g.setText("WELCOME " + user.getEmail());

    mLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutBtn);

    mLogout.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == mLogout){

        mAuth.signOut();
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you testing in a device or in emulator?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please help us by including more details in your question about what you are trying to achieve, what the issue is (including logcat output and stacktraces of exceptions that you get) and have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, please reduce your code example to include only the parts where you think that the error might be in (have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more help on that). Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
startActivity(new Intent(AccountActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
```

instead of

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please explain how your solution works rather than only posting code. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Abbas and welcome!  @vatbub is correct; please explain **why** & **how** this solves the problem.  Additionally, **please** use [Markdown formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) so your answer will be more readable.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! When you call "this" for Intent one activity to another activity, you are mentioning that activity where user now. but ultimately "this" represents the default Context of application that is MainActiity. That means user is mentioning MainActivity as AccountActivity that is false. So that you should use "AccountActivity.this" that will mention Context of AccountActivity. :) thanks